# VB.net using system.directoryservices to get displayname

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis

I am trying to get a users full name using `system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.current.displayname`
however this is returning the displayname of the domain account that is set in the application pool identity.

I have enabled windows authentication and disabled anonymous. The domain account has delegation enabled in active directory (I was told this was needed).

Any ideas how I get the current logged in users full name and not the app pool identity account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thought I'd add a little background to this for future reference.

The extra indirection for this information is because the "normal" API's tied to user identity and information are returning information from the current *execution context* associated with the running executable; in this case under IIS, that's the Application Pool identity associated with the runtime host environment (w3wp.exe) that's running the site's code.

In most web application circumstances, however, the application is interested in the identity of the user *visiting the site*. That information is negotiated between IIS and the browser, and is held within the HttpContext object that holds the current request. Identity information there is provided when **Windows Authentication** is **enabled**, and **Anonymous Authentication** is *disabled.*

Here's the code.

Try

```
Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

which should get you the identity off the Current Request from the HTTP Context.

**EDIT:** Per the comment from the OP below, this will get you the full name from AD. Be sure to set a reference to System.DirectoryServices:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] UserInfo= Context.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
   DirectoryEntry ADEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + UserInfo[0] + "/" + UserInfo[1]);
   string UserFullName = ADEntry.Properties["FullName"].Value.ToString();

}
```

**EDIT 2:** Here is a bit more contemporary one, realizing the WinNT provider kinda dates me a bit :) Be sure to strike a reference to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       var domainContext= new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
       var user  = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext,Context.User.Identity.Name);
       string userName = user.DisplayName;
}
```

**EDIT 3**: VB version, since I obviously can't read the OP's request for a VB solution :)

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

       ' Version 1, with old WinNT provider

       Dim UserInfo As String() = Context.User.Identity.Name.Split(New Char() {"\"})
       Dim ADEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + UserInfo(0) + "/" + UserInfo(1))
       Dim UserFullName As String = ADEntry.Properties("FullName").Value.ToString()

       ' Version 2, with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

       Dim DomainContext As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
       Dim User As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(DomainContext, Context.User.Identity.Name)
       Dim UserFullName2 As String = User.DisplayName

   End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. This returns the username but I'm looking for full name.

Comment: @Glenn, please note the revised answer above. It should give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks David! the page iam editing is in VB, can this be done in the same way using VB?

Comment: Arrgh!! My apologies. These can surely be done in VB. I will fix them as soon as I get to an actual keyboard (on phone right now).

Comment: VB solution provided as requested. Again, my apologies for the oversight.

Comment: No need to apologise mate you have done me a massive favour! that works great!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help.